# How can I call related tables with include option by as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

current　relation is below.

```rb
class Hoge < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :hoge_category
```

```rb
class HogeCategory < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :big_hoge_category
has_many :hoges
```

```rb
class BigHogeCategory < ApplicationRecord

has_many :hoge_categories
has_many :hoges, through: :hoge_categories
```

I want to extract `Hoge's data` which is related `HogeCategory table` and `BigHogeCategory table`.

Like this.

**HogesController**

```rb
hoges =  Hoge.index( params[:keyword], nil, params[:hoge_category_id], params[:offset].to_i, 10 ).as_json(include: :hoge_category)
render status: 200, json: { hoges: hoges } #send API
```

**Hoge.rb**

```rb
class Hoge < ApplicationRecord
searchkick callbacks: :async, language: "japanese", word_middle: [:title, :message]


def self.index(keyword, connect_id, hoge_category_id, offset, limit) #execute search
  where = {}
  if keyword.present?
    hoges = Hoge.search(keyword, fields: [:title, :message],misspellings: false, where: where, order: { created_at:  :desc }, limit: limit, offset: offset).results
  else
    hoges = Hoge.search(fields: [:title, :message],misspellings: false, where: where, order: { created_at:  :desc }, limit: limit, offset: offset).results
  end
  return hoges
end

def search_data
  {
    title: title, 
    message: message,
    created_at: created_at,
    hoge_category_id: hoge_category&.id
  }
  end
end
```

From my search, it's better to use `as_json` with `include option`.
But I don't know how to write when related tables are multiple.
How can I write that?
Or if you have a better idea, let me know please..

Comment: `as_json` is not the answer. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/better-serialization-less-as-json

Comment: What's your actual problem - translating the returned records to json, or getting the records in the first place? It's not clear from your question. Because, if you have a `@big_hoge_category` and want the `Hoge` records that belong to it where `Hoge.keyword` has value `@value`, you can use the standard Rails method `@big_hoge_category.hoges.where(keyword: @value)`. You're obviously doing a lot more than that, though, and seem to be rolling your own pagination, too. So, if you could focus your question and code, that would be really useful!